# Javascript: how can I judge an element is in viewport?

Tags: javascript, scrollview

I have a `<ul>` element. It's CSS overflow property is `scroll`.
I have several list elements in the list, such that there is a scrollbar.

```html
<ul style="overflow: scroll; height: 100px;">
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   ...
   <li></li> // how can I judge if this element is in the viewport?
</ul>
```

How can I determine if a specific list item is visible in that list?

Also, if it's not currently visible, what property can I use to make it scroll into view?

PS: No libraries, please *(jQuery, MooTools, etc)*.

Comment: jQuery is pure JavaScript. It has to be, because it's executed as JavaScript. I think better wording is in order, lol. As for an answer, I'll research a little for you.

Comment: @JoeSimmons, does this match the wording you want: "No external JavaScript libraries."

Comment: Yea, "no libraries" would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a function I just came up with.

I did some testing on the jsFiddle link at the end of this answer, and it seems consistent.

---

```js
function elementInViewOfParent(elem) {
    var container = elem.parentNode;
    return (container.scrollTop + container.offsetHeight) >= elem.offsetTop &&
           (container.scrollTop - elem.offsetHeight) <= elem.offsetTop;
}
```

---

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/e5pnN/2/) - Just scroll it wherever you want, and click the button.
It checks for the red `LI`'s visiblity, in this example.

Answer (score -1):

If you are okay with using jQuery, this will scroll so that `elem` is visible and at the top.

```
function scrollTo(elem) {
    var offset = $(elem).offset();
    $(window).scrollTop(offset.top);
}
```

(You could even animate the scroll: [jQuery scroll to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)).

Another solution would be to use `<a target="foo"></a>`, and the change the URL fragment to scroll to a particular element, but you specifically asked to be able to tell from JavaScript, which this does not allow you to do.

Comment: Well, jQeury's `offset` is nontrivial, but I believe you will have to rewrite it (or carefully copy and paste) to get what you want.